# Get extended object from multiple decoration

Tags: ruby

Using [`SimpleDelegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html), I created a few decorators to add extra functionalities to my objects. I need to decorate an object twice, as below:

```
Tracked.new(Audited.new(User.new))).save
```

Here is the basic structure of the decorator(s):

```
class Tracked #or Audited
  delegate :id, to: :__getobj__

  def initialize(extened_object)
    super(extened_object)
    @extened_object = extened_object
  end

  def itself
    __getobj__
  end

  def save
    super
    # the extended behavior
  end
end
```

I want to access the class `User` from the object. In `Audited`, if I call `@extended_object.class` with `Audited.new(User.new)).save`, I get `User`. In `Tracked`, if I call `@extended_object.class` with `Tracked(Audited.new(User.new))).save`, I get `Audited` instead.

How can I get the Class of the `extended_object` regardless of the number of times I decorate it?

Comment: Did you try to add `delegate :original_class, to: :__getobj__` to decorators and in `User` class add something like `alias original_class class`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `SimpleDelegator`.

You need to implement this method yourself.

For example:

```
class MyDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  def original_object
    obj = __getobj__
    obj.is_a?(MyDecorator) ? obj.original_object : obj
  end
end
```

And all of your decorators should be inherited from `MyDelegator`

Comment: I have accepted this solution, instead of what proposed by @MartinZinovsky because it doesn't require to modify the `User` class.